# Azure Webjob - Timeout when trying to open ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, google-chrome, webjob

I'm trying to use Azure WebApps, with Webjobs, to Test applications.
Locally, it works great. But when I build to cloud it happens the problem listed above.

Apperently the file was found, but it stays wainting until timeout.

Does anybody knows how to solve this?
I'm using C# Selenium WebDriver.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Ololu_WebJob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Url = "my_url";

            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}

/*
    LOG:
    [02/10/2019 12:27:51 > 7f9c27: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
    [02/10/2019 12:27:51 > 7f9c27: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'Ololu_WebJob.exe' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
    [02/10/2019 12:27:53 > 7f9c27: SYS INFO] Run script 'chromedriver.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
    [02/10/2019 12:27:53 > 7f9c27: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
    [02/10/2019 12:27:53 > 7f9c27: INFO] Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1) on port 9515
    [02/10/2019 12:27:53 > 7f9c27: INFO] Only local connections are allowed.
    [02/10/2019 12:27:53 > 7f9c27: INFO] Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    [02/10/2019 12:31:55 > 7f9c27: ERR ] Command 'cmd /c ""chromedriv ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
    cmd /c ""chromedriver.exe""
    [02/10/2019 12:31:55 > 7f9c27: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
    [02/10/2019 12:31:55 > 7f9c27: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c ""chromedriv ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
    cmd /c ""chromedriver.exe""
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\IdleManager.cs:line 45
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProcessExtensions.cs:line 212
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 255
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 216
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteReturnExitCode(ITracer tracer, Action`1 onWriteOutput, Action`1 onWriteError, String arguments, Object[] args) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 165
       at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger, String runId, String trigger, ITracer tracer, Int32 port) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Jobs\BaseJobRunner.cs:line 272
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) ExitCode: -1, Output: Command 'cmd /c ""chromedriv ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Error: Command 'cmd /c ""chromedriv ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c ""chromedriv ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
    cmd /c ""chromedriver.exe""
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\IdleManager.cs:line 45
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProcessExtensions.cs:line 212
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 255<---

*/
```

Comment: Just setting the url doesn’t do anything. you have to use `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);`. Next you should await the navigation, to get the Title.

Comment: No, it does! The code above is only an example, but it does work properly on any computer. It show the error on Azure Webapp Webjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, you can not directly use selenium and chromedriver without an installed instance of Chrome or Chromium on Azure WebApp, as the requirement of ChromeDriver [Setup](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) said below.

> - **Ensure Chromium/Google Chrome is installed in a recognized location**
>
> ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for your platform. You can also force ChromeDriver to use a custom location by setting a special capability.

However, due to some restricts of Azure WebApp sandbox which include [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) and [`Local Address Requests`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#local-address-requests), you could not start Chrome or Chromium without GDI support via chromedriver even if you uploaded a portable distribution of Chrome or Chromium into Azure WebApp and configured environment variables.

Although your error information did not point out the real reason of the issue in your C# code, I got the error information in Python on Azure WebApp as below.

[image]

So a workaround way is to directly use selenium and chromedriver on Azure VM. Or considering for your scenario, you can start `chromedriver` on default port `9515` on Azure VM and configure the VM NSG role to allow the inbound of port 9515, then to use class [`OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver`](https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/class/OpenQA.Selenium.Remote/RemoteWebDriver) to connect the remote webdriver in Azure WebJob.

Here is a sample code for using `RemoteWebDriver` which comes from [C# (CSharp) OpenQA.Selenium.Remote RemoteWebDriver.FindElement Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/OpenQA.Selenium.Remote/RemoteWebDriver/FindElement/php-remotewebdriver-findelement-method-examples.html)

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://<vm host ip>:9515"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

Comment: @MarceloCintra Any update or concern? If my answer is helpful for you, could you mark it?